# What is the meaning of these characters 'M','L','c','h','z' in Android vector file

Tags: android

I imported a .svg file to vector drawable file using android studio and then the IDE created an xml file in Folder: res/drawable. 
     I think android will drawing the drawable file like Canvas.drawPath. And the value of **android:pathData** is almost the points of the path. But I don't know what is the meaning of the value. 
     I guest:

> M : moveTo 
>   L : lineTo

What is the meaning of these characters in Android vector:

```
<path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M11,9h2L13,6h3L16,4h-3L13,1h-2v3L8,4v2h3v3zM7,
18c-1.1,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2S5.9,22 7,22s2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM17,18c-1.1,
0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2s0.89,2 1.99,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,
-2zM7.17,14.75l0.03,-0.12 0.9,-1.63h7.45c0.75,0 1.41,-0.41 1.75,-1.03l3.86,
-7.01L19.42,4h-0.01l-1.1,2 -2.76,5L8.53,11l-0.13,-0.27L6.16,6l-0.95,-2 -0.94,
-2L1,2v2h2l3.6,7.59 -1.35,2.45c-0.16,0.28 -0.25,0.61 -0.25,0.96 0,1.1 0.9,
2 2,2h12v-2L7.42,15c-0.13,0 -0.25,-0.11 -0.25,-0.25z"/>
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData, btw what do you need it for?

Comment: Yes. I finally try to draw custom animation with paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is the basic understanding of vector drawable parameters to draw path:**

```
M or m (X,Y)+
```

**moveto:** Move cursor to position, uppercase is absolute, lowercase is relative
moveto commands are followed by X,Y coordinates. There can be more than one set of coordinates following an M command, these are treated as implicit lineto commands.

```
Z or z
```

**closepath:** Draws a line from the current position of the cursor to the start position of the path. Does not have any parameters.

```
L or l (X,Y)+
```

**lineto:** Draws a line from the current position to the position specified by X,Y. Uppercase means absolute coordinates, lowercase means relative coordinates. You can have more than one set of coordinates following a lineto command. If you want specify more than one set of coordinates, it means that you’re creating a polyline (shape consisting of multiple string lines).

```
H or h (X)+
```

**Horizontal lineto** draws a horizontal line from the current cursor position to the position specified by X. If there are multiple X coordinates following the command, this is treated as a polyline. The Y coordinate remains unchanged. Uppercase H is absolute coordinates, lowercase h is relative coordinates.

```
V or v (Y)+
```

**Vertical lineto** draws a vertical line from the current cursor position to the position specified by Y. If there are multiple Y coordinates following the command, this is treated as a polyline. The X coordinate remains unchanged. Uppercase V is absolute coordinates, lowercase v is relative coordinates.

**Reference:**
https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e